# Clarification Regarding Pip Package Sub Dependencies Getting Upgraded

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, pip

I have a doubt regarding pip installation.

Suppose i have a requirements.txt file in python project as below

```
Django==4.1.7
```

While downloading **Django** it also downloads sub dependencies.

```
└─$ pip show Django
Name: Django
Version: 4.1.7
Summary: A high-level Python web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/sunil/Desktop/pypro/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: asgiref, sqlparse
Required-by:
```

From the above output we can notice that **asgiref, sqlparse** sub dependencies also got installed.

Below is the output of **pip freeze**

```
└─$ pip freeze
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.1.7
sqlparse==0.4.3
```

since **asgiref, sqlparse** aren't pinned in requirements.txt, In future if i reinstall these packages from above mentioned **requirements.txt** is it possible that **asgiref, sqlparse** get upgraded to different versions ?? Or these sub dependency packages has their versions pinned with **Django** itself ??

Any docs or pointers could be helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the subdependencies are pinned to Django itself.
You can take a look at the file `setup.cfg` in the django repository, there you can find which version of the sub dependencies are required :

> ```
> install_requires =
>     asgiref >= 3.6.0
>     sqlparse >= 0.2.2
>     tzdata; sys_platform == 'win32'
> ```
>
> https://github.com/django/django/blob/f9fe062de5fc0896d6bbbf3f260b5c44473b3c77/setup.cfg#L39

For example for `sqlparse`, it says it wants higher than `0.2.2`, so if a new version is available, it will upgrade this dependency (that's why you have version `0.4.3` in your output of `pip freeze`).